# python reading multiple lines to 1 dimension in 2D list from file

Tags: python, list, storing-data

I have text file which looks like this:

```
Cat
Beth
12
female
Dog
Bob
10
male
...
..
.
```

I want to store it like this: 
**myList** = [
["Cat", "Beth", "12", "female"],
["Dog", "Bob", "10", "male"], ...
]

I came up with this idea.
My question: Is there a shorter way to do this?

```
with open("sample.txt") as myFile:
   myList = []
   temp = []
   bit = 1
   for line in myFile:
       temp.append(line.strip())
       if bit % 4 == 0:
           myList.append(temp)
           temp = []
       bit += 1
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/312644/1084416

Comment: What do you mean shorter?